# Cannot get AAD auth token in Logic Apps

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-logic-apps

My Azure Logic App attempts to make an authenticated HTTP call to another API, but it fails to get an access token.

- `api`, Application ID `2222-2222-2222-2222`: The app registration for the API.
- `logic`, Application ID `3333-3333-3333-3333`: An app registration for the Logic App.
- In `logic`, I have created a client secret `secretValue`.
- In `logic`, I have added Application permission `access_as_application` in `api`, and in `api`, I have granted this permission.

In Logic App, I use these values:

- **Authentication type**: Active Directory OAuth
- **Authority**: (blank)
- **Tenant**: `1111-1111-1111-1111`
- **Audience**: `2222-2222-2222-2222`
- **Client ID**: `3333-3333-3333-3333`
- **Credential Type**: Secret
- **Secret**: `secretValue`

But I get:

```
The audience '2222-2222-2222-2222' is invalid
```

Documentation is not clear on the format to use for `Audience`, so I have tried:

- `2222-2222-2222-2222`
- `api://2222-2222-2222-2222`
- `api://2222-2222-2222-2222/.default`
- `api://2222-2222-2222-2222/access_as_application`

But none of them gives me a token.

Comment: Could you include how u added Application permission `access_as_application` by editing your question with Portal screenshots?

Comment: Did you try getting access token in this [way](https://i.imgur.com/YL38KJD.png)?

Comment: Thanks, no, I didn't try it like that. I used the built-in AAD auth option. But I'll go ahead and give this a try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I created two app registrations named `API app` and `LogicApp` in Azure AD tenant.

In API app, I configured **App ID URI** and created one **App role** named `access_as_application` as below:

[image]

Now, I added this permission in `LogicApp` and granted **admin consent** to it like this:

[image]

In my Azure Logic App workspace, I ran below `HTTP` request and got **access token** successfully in response:

**Method:** POST

**URI**:  `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/token`

**Headers:** `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

**Body:**

```
client_id="LogicAppId"
&client_secret="LogicAppSecret"
&scope=api://ApiAppId/.default
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

When I decoded this token by pasting it in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms), I got **`aud`** and **`roles`** claims as below:

[image]